# How to terminate javaw.exe when jetty web browser is closed

Tags: java, embedded-jetty

I have a javaw application called VcctlWrapper.jar that starts an embedded jetty session, opening a browser window and allowing the user to enter data into a derby database, etc.  The application is currently being launched with this command:

```
start javaw -classpath "lib/derby.jar:lib/derbytools.jar" -jar "VcctlWrapper.jar"
```

At the moment, when the user is done with the application, the only way to terminate the javaw.exe application appears to be by opening the task manager and ending the associated process manually.  I would like to find a way to have javaw.exe terminate automatically when the user closes the web browser.  Is this possible?

The source code making up the VcctlWrapper is pretty short so I'm including it in its entirety here:

```
package vcctl;

import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;   
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.*;


public class webServiceRunner extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private URI uri;
    private Desktop desktop;
    private Desktop.Action action = Desktop.Action.OPEN;

    /** Creates new form webServiceRunner */
    public webServiceRunner() {
        // initComponents();

        try {
            startJettyServer();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        try {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                try {
                   uri = new URI( "http://localhost:8080/vcctl" );
                } catch (URISyntaxException urisex) {
                }
                desktop.browse( uri );
            }

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
        }

    }


/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 152, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
        .add(0, 63, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

protected static void startJettyServer() throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    System.out.println("Current relative path is: " + s);
    String warPath = s + "/vcctl.war";
    webapp.setContextPath("/vcctl");
    webapp.setWar(warPath);
    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ webapp, new DefaultHandler()});
    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new webServiceRunner().setVisible(false);

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to open taskmanager you can call `taskkill /f /im javaw.exe` from your console. It's not a solution, but it's faster than openning task manager.

Comment: Agreed, it is faster.  But I have users of this application who would prefer to not do anything "under the hood".  They will expect the process to be killed when the web browser closes.

Answer (score 1):

how about a SessionListener, when it detects the session is destroyed it exits the process ([http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29))

i know this wouldn't be immediate, it would last as long as the session does after the browser is closed, but it's the best i can think of

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like a good solution, but I don't know how to begin. Are there any step-by-step tutorials for how to do this?  Is it something I can simply add to the code above?

Comment: ok, off the top of my head, something like this, in web.xml add  <listener>
  <listener-class>com.mydomain.SessionListener</listener-class>
 </listener> then create the com.mydomain.SessionListener class that implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener and overwrite the public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionBindingEvent) method, to do a System.exit(0); for example. I haven´t tested it but i guess it should work, let me know.

Comment: oh, and don't forget to set the session timeout in web.xml to something reasonable  <session-config>
  <session-timeout>3</session-timeout>
 </session-config>

Comment: hi @JeffBullard did it work? maybe someone else can benefit from your feedback